# Determine the radius of convergence of the following power series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

Hello I want to find the radius of convergence of the following power series
$$\sum_{}\left(\frac{1 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot \cdot \cdot (2n-1)}{2 \cdot 4 \cdot 6 \cdot \cdot \cdot (2n)}\right)^4\left(\frac{x}{3}\right)^n$$
What I tried to do was to find $∣\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}∣$ and it appears to be as follows $∣\left(\frac{2n}{2n+1}\right) \cdot \frac{3}{x}∣$ And that converges to $\frac{3}{x}$, however I am not sure if I made a calculation error or what I can do, any help? thanks.

Comment: So your question is "any help?" ?

Comment: Is the radius of convergence the set of values of $x$ for which $\lim_{n\to\infty}\vert\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\vert<1 $  ?

Comment: Please **edit the question** to spell out your calculations.  I believe you'll find you've made an arithmetic error.  A couple, actually, but only one of them will turn out to be material.

Comment: It can be easier in dealing with the algebra to write the implied divisions as multiplications by reciprocals:  $$|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}| \ \ = \ \ \left| \ \left(\frac{1 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdots (2n-1) (2n+1)}{2 \cdot 4 \cdot 6 \cdots (2n)(2n+2)}\right)^4 \ · \ \left(\frac{2 \cdot 4 \cdot 6 \cdots (2n)}{1 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdots (2n-1)}\right)^4 \ · \ \left(\frac{x}{3}\right)^{n+1} ·  \left(\frac{3}{x}\right)^n \ \right| \ \ . $$  The radius of convergence is finite.